# Importing Data with CSV

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I am wondering what I would need to do in order to import a CSV file and then combined that with an existing layer.

I would like to know which boxes I need to check in order to make this combine with another layer.

If you could also walk me through the step by step procedures if we need to write any expressions in the field calculator that would be great.

If it helps I downloaded the original Layer with all the Data points on it and then Added a field and would like to re-add it into QGIS.

Comment: Can you give examples of your data?

Comment: I think this depends on how your data is stored in your csv. E.g. which delimiters are used (commas, tabs, spaces...); are column names present and if so, which row are they in; if there's geometry stored, how are they stored (are they point coordinates using XY coordinates), lines or polygons using WKT format, or no geometry at all (just an attribute table). Quite a lot of factors involved but there is a preview window which shows how your data will be represented with the selected options. If it looks right then try to add it =)

Comment: You don't join data in the CSV importer. Perhaps you need two question instead of one. In the CSV importer just hit all the checkboxes depending on you delimiter, till you are happy with the result. You can join under under properties to another layer.

Comment: I have 5 different columns, Each has a name at the top which is the Field. When I exported the original document from Qgis it had coordinates, but I believe that I only exported the Attributes. The delimiter is commas.

Comment: I guess my main question is; How do I join a Attributes only layer with one that has Geometry in it.

Comment: @Micklus - If both layers have a common field, you can double-click your geometry layer > **Joins** > click the green plus button > select the attribute layer and the common field for both the join and target field.

Comment: @Joseph That is what I have been trying to do, whenever I do that though, it just says NULL in the field when I look at the attributes table afterwords. Each layer has the same 5 different fields; AREASYMBOL SPATIALVER MUSYM MUKEY Drainage, each of the first 4 fields have the same data, and I am trying to compile those in the drainage field.

Comment: @Micklus - As Matt suggested, it might be easier if you could upload your layers on a public server so that others could test it. Also, there is a tool from the _Processing Toolbox_ called `Join attributes table` which might be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, right-click on a layer with geometry and go in Properties.
There, click on the Joins tab on the left (it looks like an arrow with a dot).
Then click on `+` and chose the layers and fields on which you want to do the Join.